# Решение задания на Java

Tags: java

Есть задача:
Для того чтобы выходить в Интернет, каждому компьютеру присваивается так называемый IP-адрес. Он состоит из четырех целых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 255, разделенных точками. В следующих трех строках показаны три правильных IP-адреса:
127.0.0.0
192.168.0.01
255.00.255.255
Напишите программу, которая определяет, является ли заданная строка правильным IP-адресом.
Входные данные:
На вход программе подается строка длиной не более 15 символов, которая включает цифры и точки.
Выходные данные:
Если строка является правильным IP-адресом, необходимо вывести YES, иначе NO.

Я ее решил так:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ipAddress = scan.nextLine();
    boolean is_valid_IP = true;
    int amountOfDots = 0;
    int amountOfChars = 0;
    int currentNum = 0;
    if (ipAddress.isEmpty()) {
        is_valid_IP = false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddress.length(); i++) {
            char x = ipAddress.charAt(i);
            if (x == '.') {
                amountOfDots++;
                if (currentNum > 255) {
                    is_valid_IP = false;
                    break;
                }
                currentNum = 0;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(x)) { // Character.IsDigit - метод для проверки является ли символ цифрой
                currentNum = currentNum * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(x);
                amountOfChars++;
            } else {
                is_valid_IP = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (amountOfDots != 3 || amountOfChars > 15 || currentNum > 255 || amountOfChars == 0) {
        is_valid_IP = false;
    }
    System.out.println(is_valid_IP? "YES" : "NO");
```

Но этот код не проходит 7 тест. Что в этом тесте - неизвестно. Можете помочь. Заранее спасибо.
[Платформа на которой выполняю задание. Раздел 1.16](https://stepik.org/lesson/399119/step/14?unit=388209)

Comment: Например "8.8.8." должно быть NO, а выводит YES

Comment: Ну и неправильный подход. Нужно инициализировать ``is_valid_IP`` значением false и потом ставить ``true``, если строка удовлетворяет всем условиям. Позволит избавиться от проверки ``ipAddress.isEmpty()`` и вообще сократить код. Переменная ``amountOfChars`` вообще не нужна, т.к. ничего нового не дает.

Comment: `192.168.0.01` не годный IP-адрес. Что там в 7м тесте? Или на курс нужно записаться? И что-то алгоритм у Вас какой-ти мудрёный... Не проще ли разбить строку по точкам в массив и проверять его? Длину строки можно проверять сразу. Если amountOfChars не увеличивается при точках, то и сравнивайте не с 15, а с 12. Дополнительно строку можно очистить от ведущих и конечных пробельных символов с trim() или с strip().

Comment: @XelaNimed 192.168.0.01 годный конечно же. Чего бы ему быть негодным?

Comment: @Эникейщик ни разу [с таким](https://superuser.com/a/857618/911786) не сталкивался... Если принять во внимание и такой формат, то 15 символами здесь уже не ограничишься, т.к. `0377` в вомеричном формате представляет `255` и является корректным.

Comment: @XelaNimed 0377 является восьмеричным форматом только в некоторых заранее известных и определенных случаях. А программы, куда вводятся айпишники, принимают числа в десятичном формате.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну к примеру команда ping понимает такой формат...

Comment: @XelaNimed О, блин, точно. Не обратил внимания, что там потом другие числа пишутся. Но это все равно выходит за рамки учебной задачи :)

Comment: https://jdoodle.com/a/6uNN IP-адреса для проверки вбивать в текстовое поле "CommandLine Arguments" через пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решал эту задачу подругому, а именно разделением строки по точкам с последующей проверкой каждого октета.

```java
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter min. one IP-Address for check");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        for( String ip : args )
        {
            String[] octets = ip.split("\\.");
            if(octets.length != 4)
            {
                System.out.println( ip + " is wrong, because IP-address v.4 must contain exactly 4 octets");
                continue;
            }
            boolean error = false;
            for(String octet : octets)
            {
                int octetInt = octet.startsWith("0")
                            ? Integer.parseInt(octet, 8)
                            : Integer.parseInt(octet);
                if(octetInt < 0 || octetInt > 255)
                {
                    System.out.println( ip + " is wrong, because contains octet " + octetInt + " outer range 0-255");
                    error = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if(!error)
            {
                System.out.println( ip + " is correct");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Поиграться с кодом можно [здесь](https://jdoodle.com/a/6uNN). IP-адреса для проверки вводить в текстовое поле "CommandLine Arguments" через пробел. Поддерживаются октеты в восьмеричном формате.

Answer (score 0):

Если стоит задача проверить строку на соответствие формату, это лучше выполнять в виде отдельного метода, чтобы упростить тестирование и отделить собственно проверку от ввода данных.  Также такой метод должен просто возвращать булево значение, а не заниматься печатью сообщений.

Таким образом, следует реализовать метод с сигнатурой

```java
public static boolean isValidIp4(String ipAddress);
```

При реализации следует сперва проверить простейшие ограничения по длине входной строки -- кроме максимума в 15 символов есть и ограничение снизу в 7 символов (4 цифры + 3 точки).

Проверить, что строка содержит ровно 4 целых числа в заданном диапазоне можно разными способами:

- сканер строки, с делимитером `"\\."` -- такой способ защищён от исключений при парсинге чисел

```java
public static boolean isValidIp4(String ipAddress) {
    if (null == ipAddress || ipAddress.length() < 7 || ipAddress.length() > 15) {
        return false;
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ipAddress).useDelimiter("\\.");
    int count = 0;
    
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num < 0 || num > 255) {
            return false;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 4 == count;
}
```

- разбиение по точке при помощи `String::split` (как в предыдущем ответе), и `Integer::parseInt`, с обработкой соответствующего исключения для пустых строк / строк, не содержащих десятичные числа.

```java
public static boolean isValidIp4(String ipAddress) {
    if (null == ipAddress || ipAddress.length() < 7 || ipAddress.length() > 15) {
        return false;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (String s : ipAddress.split("\\.")) {
        try {
            int d = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (d < 0 || d > 255) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException numex) {
            return false;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 4 == count;
}
```

- Использование [регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/aPCfu4/1) (без восьмеричной записи) и `String.matches`:

```java
public static boolean isValidIp4(String ipAddress) {
    
    return null != ipAddress && ipAddress.length() > 6 && ipAddress.length() < 16
        && ipAddress.matches("(([1-9]|1\\d|2[0-4])?\\d|25[0-5])(\\.(([1-9]|1\\d|2[0-4])?\\d|25[0-5])){3}");
}
```